# What is the best way to reshape and/or slice this array to create the desired pairs of items using NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have two "records" shaped like the following:

```
loaded_data = np.arange(58)
loaded_data = np.vstack((loaded_data, loaded_data))
```

Output:

> [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
>   23   24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
>   46 47   48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57]
>   [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
>   10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23   24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
>   33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47   48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
>   56 57]]

How would I reshape or slice the data such that I could have a new array that would look like the following without having to iterate through?:
[[0 0]
 [1 1]
 [2 2]
 ...
 [57 57]]

I can pull out the pairs individually like this after I reshape:

```
reshaped = loaded_data.reshape((2,29, 2))
print(reshaped[:,0,0])
```

> [0 0]

Is there a way to get my desired list using slicing without having to iterate over the list? If not, how would you accomplish this in the most Pythonic way?

Comment: Please assume the call to vstack is not made: I used that to create the test data to represent what I'm trying to manipulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I'd use `numpy.column_stack`:

```
>>> loaded_data = np.arange(5)
>>> np.column_stack((loaded_data, loaded_data))
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 4]])
```

If you're really stuck with the `vstack` (e.g. the stacking command is in a routine you don't want to change), you can just take the transpose (using the [`.T`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html) property of numpy arrays or [`np.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html):

```
>>> np.vstack((loaded_data, loaded_data)).T
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 4]])
```

Comment: This is great - I used vstack to simulate the actual data that I load via a npy file.  Would this still work for that? I'll be testing really quickly but how would you do it assuming the data was already in the format vstack was used to create?

Comment: @ChirisTownsend -- See my edit.  You can just take the transpose using the `.T` property.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That works great on the vstack data.  What if the data is in that format but not due to a call to vstack, it just loads that way from a numpy file?